# multiple char replace with regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

need massive char replace with regexp:

```
  before -->  h e l l o
              | | | | |
  result -->  a b c c d
```

how? :)

actually, need to replace the all characters Unicode (UTF-8) to ASCII (Unicode Escaped) in html :) this question just is a simplified example

upd

okay, always forget that can search in text by regular expression but can't replace, issue resolved, thank you

Comment: There's not enough background to say.  Generally, this is not a job for a regular expression but more information is needed to answer the question appropriately for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: actually, need to replace the all characters Unicode (UTF-8) to ASCII (Unicode Escaped) in html :) this question just is a simplified example

Comment: I'd probably use tr for any character translation (single-single char translation such as h to a) in a file.  If sublime can perform encoding changes, that might also do the trick.  If what you're looking for is changing ד into \u05D3, that might be accomplished in python via repr a la repr(u'ד') -> u'\u05d3'.  Otherwise, I suspect you're going to need to do these one at a time or perhaps make a tool to do it.  The tool would not be complex.

Comment: annoying, but sublime can't save the document in Unicode Escaped,
no such option

Comment: I think I understand your use case.  I've made a little thing to help you out, assuming I've got a good handle on what you're needing.  You should probably change the question and tags to describe better what you're trying to accomplish since a regex replace to do this is realistically impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should serve your purposes.  I saved it in utf-to-ascii.py.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

for c in sys.stdin.read().decode('UTF-8'):
    charcode = ord(c)
    if charcode > 127:
        sys.stdout.write('\\u%04x'%(charcode))
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
```

I tested it with a file called textdoc.txt with these contents:

```
hello ד blah blah
```

I ran it like so:

```
$ ./utf-to-ascii.py <textdoc.txt 
hello \u05d3 blah blah
```

To save that output to a file, you'd run this:

```
$ ./utf-to-ascii.py < textdoc.txt > textdoc.transformed.txt
```

Comment: respect for support, James!